# Does the JPA 2.0 EntityManager respect the current Namespace in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, namespaces, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

### How do I get JPA to respect the Namespace I am setting when it generates keys?

I am using the following code to get the current user and set the `Namespace` to their `UserId`:

```
final OAuthService oauth = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
final User user = oauth.getCurrentUser();
NamespaceManager.set(user.getUserId());
```

When I do the following I get the correctly information in my logs:

```
System.out.println("user.getUserId() = " + user.getUserId());
System.out.println("user.toString() = " + user.toString());
```

Here is how I am creating my `Key` inside the constructor of my `Entity`:

```
@Entity
public class ImageHandle
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonSerialize(using = com.vertigrated.gae.cms.jackson.KeySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = com.vertigrated.gae.cms.jackson.KeyDeserializer.class)
    private Key key;
 ....
```

First thing I do in the constructor is :

```
this.key = KeyFactory.createKey(ImageHandle.class.getSimpleName(), uuid.toString());
```

The Google App Engine documentation says that the `KeyFactory` should use whatever the current `NamespaceManager.get()` returns, but it doesn't.

When I do the following code and I get the `Namespace` set to `""` as output, even though I have set it to the `user.getUserId()` in the code above:

```
final ImageHandle ir = new ImageHandle(fs.getBlobKey(aef), uuid, url, name, w, h, s);
ENTITY_MANAGER.persist(ir);
System.out.println("ir.getKey().getNamespace() = " + ir.getKey().getNamespace());
```

Results in the output : `ir.getKey().getNamespace() =`

No `Namespaces` show up in the `DataStore Viewer` in the administration console either.

#### Does the JPA EntityManager in Google App Engine respect the current `Namespace` settings?

Comment: Respect the Namespace setting? What are you talking about? JPA will save your entity as long as it is setup and populated correctly. It is 100% unaware of Google App Engine. It would be infinitely more helpful if you included your entity code for `ImageHandle` and `Key`, and the code that you use to populate them.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

I figured out what the problem was, I am calling another method that is setting the `Namespace` in a finally block to my default `Namespace`, once I moved the `NamespaceManager.set(user.getUserId());` below that method call, it fixed it.

#### Lesson Learned

I should be getting the current `Namespace`, storing it and and setting it back like the examples.